# undefined method `new' for Driver:Module Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So, the set up is very simple. In my controller I have

```
class DriverController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def new
    @driver = Driver.new
  end
end
```

And the new.html.erb is

```
<h1>Driver#new</h1>
<%= form_for @driver do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

When I try to acess that new page it says: "undefined method `new' for Driver:Module"
When I change def new in my controller to def create for an example, this error goes away and it says that First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<h1>Driver#new</h1>
<%= form_for :driver, :url: drivers_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

In routes.rb

```
resourse :drivers
```

And further I would suggested you yo Visit [Guide Ruby on Rails the-first-form](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#the-first-form)

Hope this help you !!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where the problem was, but I just did everything all over again, and it worked.